# Is there a way to fix a CoreDNS deploy in AKS which is always on CrashLoopBackOff?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, deployment, azure-aks, coredns

To bring some context, I was using AKS and have deployed a APIM solution on a cluster, which was working fine for a month, but some days ago, I went back on my cluster and the CoreDNS & the CoreDNS autoscaler pods are on a CrashBackLoop.

Here are the descriptions of the Pod:

- I've tried to scale the deployment
- Restarted the deployment
- Deleted the pods, updated the deployment image

But none of the actions I did worked so far, if anyone have any suggestions

Here are the deployments files if it can help: [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check the pod logs `kubectl logs <podname> -n <namespace>`?Also when you add the mainfest add it using a code blog don't add the image

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answers and for the advices, I'm new on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

I partially resolved my problem by restarting my cluster on AKS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).